# Adding new linked items in database

Tags: website-design, input-fields, data-entry

I am pretty new to creating UXes in general and I'm working on a database management tool. Among other things there are tables for Members and Institutions. Institutions have multiple members, members belong to one institution. In addition, each institution has one primary member who is the point of contact. Each member would have one InstitutionId matching an existing institution, and each institution would have one MemberId for the primary member, matching an existing member.

Are there any proscribed principles of UX for this? If I create the institution before I create the primary member, I would have to leave that field blank as a MemberId doesn't exist yet. If I create any member before creating the institution I have to leave that field blank too. They can go in and edit the field in either case, but it doesn't seem like a great idea to leave it blank and have the user forget.

One solution I'm working with is to have a checkbox when creating a new member to set them as the primary member for their institution, and if a primary member already exists for that institution, to ask the user if they're sure they want to update that. The problem is that this still leaves the possibility of an institution having no primary member but they may not want to have that as a possibility. I could also have the primary MemberId as a required field, with a tab to create a new member with that InstitutionId already assigned.

Ultimately I'll be asking the customer what they want to do but I don't expect them to have good ideas to suggest off the bat so ideally I'll have a couple options to give them.

Comment: Hi Frank, it is a bit unclear what your problem is from the question. What I get is that you feel unsure how to design a system where there are invalid states (e.g. an institution has no primary member). Now you can either a) force the user to only allow valid states (when creating an institution you also have to assign a primary member) or b) allow invalid states and give the user the opportunity to fix them later. Maybe you should design different variants and show that to the user/customer.

Comment: Hi Nash, that's a great answer. I know it's bad form to ask this kind of vague question on SO, so thanks for helping in a way that lets me think about the general problem in a clearer way. I don't know that there's a good way to focus the question better, but if you post that comment as an answer I'll definitely accept it!